# Record audio NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, electron

We are using **Electron** to record the voice of the **speaker** "the person using the Electron application" and the **counterpart** "who is on the other side of the conversation". I can use "*Naudiodon*" to record the speaker's voice but how do I record the counterpart's voice? In other words, how do I record what goes into the **loudspeaker** of the speaker?

Comment: Can you explain your question better?

Comment: In most cases, it will be easier to solve this by recording the audio **from** a source rather than trying to intercept everything going **to** an output. You haven't said what the audio source is though.

Comment: @D.Pardal I will try my best. We have an analysis system that takes text. We need to analyze the conversation in real-time. We are working on an Electron app that will record meetings like Zoom. And then in real-time send both the conversations to our analysis system and get results of the conversation. So that the speaker understands the psychological aspects of the other person talking. For this we need to record both the person using our app and the person with whom she is talking. Question is, how do I record the other person who is on the other side of the conversation.

Comment: @Quentin we do not have control over other person and they are not our customers. So we cannot tell them to record their talks. Our customers are using Electron and we need to record both talks using Electron.

Comment: @sediqkhan — The other person is not connecting directly to your speaker. The audio has to be getting to it through some local piece of software, presumably the electron app you've told us very little about. Something in that app is the source that is outputting audio to the speaker.

Comment: @Quentin you are correct. We do not foresee using what tool/software another person's voice reaches our computer. Maybe something like Zoom or Skype or... so we leave that open "if we have to or possible". But we need to record what goes into the loudspeaker of our customer.

Comment: Did you solve this @sediqkhan ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use the deviceid in your naudiodon input option? normally specify the system audio input deviceid is ok (with getdevices()).